# Combine list of x,y-coordinates with list of densities for ListDensityPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I have a list of x-, and y-coordinates $(\{\{x_1,y_1\},\{x_2,y_2\},...\})$:

```
xy:={{0., 0.}, {0., 0.25}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 0.75}, {0., 1.0}}
```

corresponding to a list of densities $(\{f_1,f_2,...\})$:

```
f:={0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25}
```

How do I combine them in the correct format for ListDensityPlot $(\{\{x_1,y_1,f_1\},\{x_2,y_2,f_2\},...\})$?

```
xyf:={{0., 0., 0.25}, {0., 0.25, 0.5}, {0., 0.5, 0.75}, {0., 0.75, 0.5}, {0., 1.0, 0.25}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example

```
MapThread[Append, {xy, f}]
```

or

```
Append @@@ Transpose[{xy, f}]
```

or

```
Flatten /@ Transpose[{xy, f}]
```

Comment: `Transpose[xy]~Join~{f} // Transpose`, because why not.

Answer (score 3):

```
xy = {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.25}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 0.75}, {0., 1.0}};

f = {0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[f &, Append[1] /@ xy, {All, -1}]
```

{{0., 0., 0.25}, {0., 0.25, 0.5}, {0., 0.5, 0.75}, {0., 0.75, 0.5}, {0., 1., 0.25}}

Answer (score 2):

```
xy = {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.25}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 0.75}, {0., 1.0}};
f = {0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25};

Join[xy, List /@ f, 2]
MapThread[Join, {xy, List /@ f}]
MapThread[{Sequence @@ #1, #2} &, {xy, f}]
MapThread[Catenate[{#1, {#2}}] &, {xy, f}]
MapIndexed[Append[#1, First@f[[#2]]] &, xy]
Thread[{xy, f}] // Map[FlattenAt[#, 1] &]
```

---

*Result:*

{{0., 0., 0.25}, {0., 0.25, 0.5}, {0., 0.5, 0.75}, {0., 0.75,
0.5}, {0., 1., 0.25}}

Answer (score 1):

```
xy = {{0., 0.}, {0., 0.25}, {0., 0.5}, {0., 0.75}, {0., 1.0}};

f = {0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25};
```

---

Using `Thread` as follows:

```
Activate@Thread[{Inactive[Sequence] @@ # & /@ xy, f}]
```

*Result*:

> {{0., 0., 0.25}, {0., 0.25, 0.5}, {0., 0.5, 0.75}, {0., 0.75, 0.5}, {0., 1., 0.25}}